# Update value on a database with jQuery

Tags: php, ajax, post, sql-update

I have a database table where i have two fields (besides the ID): 'name' and 'value'.
I expect the 'value' field to always be '0' or '1'.

Now, i have a page where i am displaying all the names on this table using a PHP while loop. What i want is that everytime i click on a name, i'll change the 'value' field of that row to '0' or '1'.
So, if i have a row where the name is 'John Doe' and the value is '0', when i click it, i'll change the value to '1'. I would like to do this with Ajax so the page doesn't reload, but i'm really noob with this.

What i have so far:

index.php

```
function update()
{
 var value = document.getElementById('val').innerHTML;
 var id = document.getElementById('userid').innerHTML;
 if(value == 1)
 {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'loaddata.php',
  data: {
   iduser:id,
   new_value: 0
  }
  });
 }

 else if (value == 0)
 {
    $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'loaddata.php',
  data: {
    iduser:id,
   new_val: 1
  }
  });
 }
}

<?php 
                    while($dados= $dado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        $userid = $dados['userid'];
                        $name = $dados['name'];
                        $val = $dados['value'];
                ?>



  <button onclick="update()">
<div class="linha-convidado">
<span><?php echo $name ?></span>
<span id="val"><?php echo $val ?></span>
<span id="userid"><?php echo $userid ?></span>
</div>
</button>

<?php } ?>
```

loaddata.php

```
<?php

if( isset( $_POST['entrada'] ) )
{

$id = $_POST['iduser'];
$newval = $_POST['new_value'];

$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = ' ';
$db = 'convidados';

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);


$updatedata = "UPDATE convidados set value = '$newval' WHERE userid = $id";

$query = mysqli_query($con, $updatedata);

}
?>
```

I know i am missing something (or probably a lot), but i really don't have any idea. Can you help me out?

Comment: You have non-unique `id`s as you are using the same values in a loop. Each `user` needs its own `id`

Comment: @Sean how do i fix this then since i'm using a loop? Using classes instead of Id's?

Comment: Yes, either classes or append the `$userid` to the `id="userid"` to make them unique-> `id="userid<?php echo $userid; ?>"`

Comment: @Sean i just did that, but it's still not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to make name as uniform in `JS` and `PHP` both

Just remove `if... else` use like this

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'loaddata.php',
  data: {
   iduser:id,
   new_value: value ? 0 : 1
  }
  });
```

Also you have to send value of `entrada` from ajax

to check below if condition

```
 if( isset( $_POST['entrada'] ) )
```

Comment: Actually the OP is sending `new_value` in the `if` and `new_val` in the `else if`

Comment: @OIIO thanks, but it's still not working. And regarding that if condition, it was just something i forgot to change, i have this:

if( isset( $_POST['new_value'] ) )